# Remove padding around element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to reduce the amount of border space available to to the dark area at bottom and top

So :

[image]

Should be :

[image]

I've tried adding padding-bottom: 0px !important to pds-vote. pds-vote being the vote element that I am trying to reduce the padding on but does not seem to have any effect.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/79/

Code behind the fiddle:

```css
.pds-question-top {
font-size:10pt !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-pd-link, .pds-comments {
display:none !important;
}

.pds-box {
width:220px !important;
}

.pds-input-label {
width:85% !important;
}

.PDS_Poll {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-answer-span {
color:#00f;
}

.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
}

.pds-answer-text {
color:#00f;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-answer-feedback {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-votebutton-outer {
text-align:center;
}

.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pds-input-label,.pds-answer-input {
float:left;
}

.pds-view-results,.pds-links {
color:#FFF !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-comments,.pds-return-poll {
color:#FFF !important;
}

.pds-links {
    display: inline !important;
}
.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-question-top {padding:0 !important}
```

HTML behind the fiddle:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 15px;float:left">Header</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your css 
Ofc you can set it to your desired paddings

```
 .pds-answer{
    padding-bottom:5px !Important;
}
.pds-box-outer{
  padding-bottom:5px !Important;
}
```

But you should try to avoid using important that much.

[Explanation Why](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

Comment: @Scotty sorry for that. But I saw wan not answered for 15min that I could answer :)

Comment: !important should generally be avoided in favour of using the natural css cascade, a useful article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: @Slixx I think you didn't click my link

Comment: @Liquid LOL didn't saw the link. Was only checking the code ^^ Good point there ;)

Comment: There's no need of using `!important` at all in this case, you just need to use a more specific selector.

Comment: @scumah  I didn't check on fiddle because it's down. I kinda gave it as a quick fix. Because of all his important's it's impossible to see a tree in the forrest.

Comment: @Liquid, I mean a more specific selector in terms of [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), like adding any parent id (`#`) to increase the weight of the selector.

Comment: @scumah Sorry for misunderstanding your comment. But indeed you are correct. I'll take a look into it for this answer. But that shouldn't even be necessary if he cleans up all the importants. And works his way up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#PDI_container6352993 .pds-box .pds-box-outer {
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/25LjE/85/) a fiddle with the result.